# Is the recent Java bug something to worry about?

Tags: security, java, jdk

I recently saw [this](http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Java-exploit-launches-local-Windows-applications-974652.html) announcement on the H blog about a big hole in Java, but I can't seem to get anyone to think it's a big deal. The fact that I can visit a web site and it runs calc.exe on my local box is just plain scary. Why isn't there a bigger response to this?

Comment: Are you running Java WebStart?

Comment: Not familiar with WebStart - Sun says it's "included in the Java Runtime Environment" so I would guess that everyone running Java is running WebStart.

Comment: Yes, WebStart is included with the standard JRE download from Sun, so if your browser has Java installed and working, it also has WebStart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'm not crazy - Oracle released a fix.
http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Java-vulnerability-when-lyric-sites-attack-978283.html

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess at why the Sun team doesn't consider this to be bad enough to issue an emergency update; development teams have to make calls like this and I suspect they felt that either the hole was too hard to exploit or the workaround was sufficient to prevent problems.

Anyway, if you feel strongly this is too big a risk for your system then you should implement one of the workarounds described in the article.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that the workarounds don't seem to work. I guess I was hoping for someone who knows more about Java than I do to tell me what the real risk is.

Comment: How do you make a response an "Answer"?